# Understanding of bivariate Gaussian distributions in connection with complex random variable

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate, complex-numbers

Say that we want to model a complex-valued signal using the RV $S$, where $S$ can be expressed by it's real and imaginary part, i.e. $S = X + iY$, where $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables.

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are both Gaussian, have zero mean, are independent and have the same variance. Is the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ complex-valued?

My intuition says that the joint PDF is real-valued, since the joint distribution can be viewed as a joint PDF of two orthogonal Gaussian RVs (Re{S} = X, Im{S} = Y), and thus, we can view $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ as a real-valued bivariate Gaussian distribution, where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

Is this line of thinking correct or is my intuition about the problem completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing complex about the pair $(X,Y)$, so yes, the density is real-valued. As the density of a complex-valued $S$ is defined as the density of $(X,Y)$, this is real-valued, too.

The subtlety here is that according to the standard definition obviously a density of a 2-d real-valued random variable is real valued. The standard definition does *not* cover complex-valued RVs $S$, so it has to be explicitly defined that $f_S=f_{(X,Y)}$, but this is what is done. [(Wikipedia - complex random variable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_random_variable)